# What's the most efficient way to style multiple html elements when generating them with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently building a web app for some popular software on steam and decided to generate the elements with JS. The reason for doing this is because I'm going to force a refresh after the user confirms a settings menu, and then check **localStorage** on each customizable element and act accordingly.

The problem is that while rendering the HTML elements I'm styling them individually, compared to just using a class in standard css. I looked around for a potential solution and the only one I could find was by defining the class in the css file and then applying that class through js, but I'll end up with a lot of wasted classes this way.

```
for(let i=0; i<title.length; i++) {
    // creation
    const a = document.createElement("a");

    // styling
    a.style.display = "block";
    a.style.width = "90%";
    a.style.margin = "auto";
    a.style.padding = "20px";
    a.style.backgroundColor = "#2f2f2f";

    // attaching it to element as child
    sets.appendChild(a);
}
```

This is currently how I have all my elements being created, which is less than ideal. I want to know whether or not it's possible to create a css class from within js, or at least the best method of achieving the end result. It might not be a problem at the current stage, but I'm likely going to have hundreds of elements sharing the same styling in the near future.

**thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Not related to the question but I'd suggest to use `createDocumentFragment` and make a single node insertion instead of appending multiple elements in a loop.

Comment: Also, I would suggest to not apply these styles via JS. You can have a generic CSS class that will have these styles and add that class to the element when you create it dynamically. And as suggested by @fcalderan, its good to have one insertion then multiple insertions on DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `setAttribute`

```
a.setAttribute('class', 'my-css-class');
```

You can then add the styles with css:

```
.my-css-class {
    background-color: #2f2f2f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In terms of pure efficiency, I don't think you can do a lot better than this except maybe generate an HTML string and use innerHTML but I wouldn't do that as it might save a few miliseconds but it makes the code less maintainable in the long run. The fragment is already a better alternative as suggested by @fcalderan. You can also use a CSS class as pointed by @Sirence. Also, if you care about code-style, it's a little loss on performance but a gain in readability, you can use `forEach()` instead of a classic `for` loop.

#### CSS:

```css
.set-title {
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    backgroun-color: #2f2f2f;
}
```

#### JS:

```js
let fragment = new DocumentFragment();
title.forEach(t => {
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    a.className = 'set-title';
    fragment.appendChild(a);
});
sets.appendChild(fragment);
```

Comment: I'll be using Sirence's answer because the css is clunking up my code, but I could use this method elsewhere, so thanks.